# Make robots look just like humans

Tags: science-fiction, robots, sim-humans

Creating a world where robots and humans coexist peacefully for many years, I'm thinking about some characteristcs that could make robots impersonate a human.

Until now, I have some features for this type of robot:

> - Extremely advanced AI (The [Turing Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) is a piece of cake to them and even a ["Voight-Kampff"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner) similar test could be completed successfully);
> - Some kind of natural skin really similar to the human skin;
> - Voice generator that simulate voices of real humans;
> - Possibility of eating, drinking and smoking without problems;

What other characteristics could improve this type of robot to look just like a human? There are some trap that will spoil the guise of the robot?

I'm thinking about a situation where a human definitively can't distinguish between a human and a robot (without using tools, just with physical characteristics and logical tests).

**UPDATE**

Trying to clarify my question according to the comments, here are some details:

I want to create a world where humans and robots coexist peacefully and where humans aren't capable of distinguish between humans and robots. In the history, humans will be deceived by the robots in many situations.

However, I was thinking about the physical characteristics and also about the daily situations with robot/human encounters and how these robots will disguise completely among the human. I decide that these robots have a great AI and some physical characteristics that will help in this task (listed above).

My question is precisely about these characteristics. They are sufficient or I need to improve them?

Comment: The Uncanny Valley is an excellent place to start reading up on this.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley

Comment: Nice try Skynet!

Comment: I think this question, as it stands, is a little too broad. Could you please narrow the scope of your question, or provide more guidelines so the answers aren't just opinion-based or lists?

Comment: I suggest you read either Pluto by Naoki Urasawa or Origin by Boichi both are based on different takes on this premise. Origin will give you the answers more concisely.https://boichi.com/series/ As it stands this question is too broad each one of yourr questions would be fine, but asking them all together is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the things I was able to come up with. I can add to it as I think of more or if more is added in the comments.

Huge things to overcome:

- Materials - (*Eyes, skin, hair, nails, teeth, (even whole mouth, since they talk?)*) - Their entire body needs to simulate a human's, or a simple physical could easily reveal a lack of muscles, or many other specific organs, body structures, or nerves. You may even have to account for cuts or scrapes happening.
- Movement - accurately moving like a real person is very hard. We do not usually operate with smooth or predictable movements, but neither are we jerky and random, making it difficult to program and control. There is also usually less motors in (today's) typical robot than the human body has, but maybe part of simulating the movement requires all the same muscles the human body has.
- Speech - natural sounding speech requires ability to change tone/pitch/loudness and even clarity in various ways, but not so much as to sound unhuman. Some languages even use tongue clicks and other sounds/enunciations using the mouth, not just the voice box.

---

The little things, the things you would notice after sufficient contact with one or multiple robots lacking these features:

- Unique behavior quirks
- Unique physical qualities (*All robots can't look the same, obviously - but also they can't all share the same exact ear design or pattern of moles on their face*)
- Changes over time to appearance
- Mood changes
- Simulating the human time-clock and capabilities. (*for example: If robots need to power back up every night and you can stay awake for 24 hours, then you are not a robot*) Also, matching human physical abilities such as endurance and power.

Comment: "If you can stay awake for 24 hours you are not a robot" - But can't robots do that, too?

Comment: @HDE226868 I admit the limit is likely greater than that, it was just an example that they should not just get tired when they are about to "run out of power". They have to simulate the human time-clock. Edited it a bit

Comment: It's really complicated look like a human nowadays. Thx for the help! With this list I'll improve my robots.